# how display data in crystal report in vb.net

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating an application in vb.net i m having problem with displaying multiple rows it shows too much space between two rows of data.
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a Lok at this (Marcoratti)web:
[1.VB NET+Cristal](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_crpt.htm)
[2.VB NET+Cristal](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn3_cr1.htm)